# tags <a> add click and how to add attr "active"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add click for tags `<a>` and at the same time add attribute "active" for the current `<a>`;

I had done it like this, but it doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<div class="leftFocus">
<a class="leftFocusItem active" href="/" ><i class="fa fa-fire mr5 text-red fa-fw"></i>今日动态</a>
<a class="leftFocusItem" href="/recommend"><i class="fa fa-user-plus mr5 text-violet fa-fw"></i>您的关注</a>
<a class="leftFocusItem" href="/activity" ><i class="fa fa-gamepad mr5 text-blove fa-fw"></i>热门活动</a>
<a class="leftFocusItem" href="/rank" ><i class="fa fa-trophy mr5 text-yellow fa-fw"></i>排行榜</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
$('.leftFocus a').on('click', function(){
$(this).addClass('active').siblings('.leftFocusItem').removeClass('active');
});
 });
```

How should to write the right js for this problem?

Comment: add `active` to each page

Comment: Thanks a lot for  j08691, but how should I do ? I just want the current page has attribute "active" . Could you explain it  detailed for me ? thank u so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is fine but you will lose what has been selected as soon as the browser loads a new page.

You could add `preventDefault()` to the code to stop the browser from following the link, but then the links won't work ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('.leftFocus a').on('click', function(e){
        // link will have correct class but no longer will navigate
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.leftFocusItem').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

It seems like you should instead be checking to see which link is the current path and setting the class on that, like so:

```
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.leftFocus a').forEach(function (link) { 
        if (link.href === window.location.href) { 
            link.classList.add('active'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for pixelscript , I had try as your codes  with some revise like this :   $(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    document.querySelectorAll('.leftFocus a').forEach(function (link) {
        if (link.src === window.location.pathname) {
        link.classList.add('active');
    }
});
});  for your codes in my enviroment Report errors
 ,but it seems doesn't work . Is me revise the  wrong codes?  Thanks again for pixelscript.

Comment: I had revise your codes from          document.querySelectorAll('.leftFocus a').forEach(link => {...});           to                                                       document.querySelectorAll('.leftFocus a').forEach(function (link) {...});  I changed    link =>    to      function(link)  . Is that right?   @pixelscript.

Comment: Oh yeah that's fine, I was just using ES6 syntax ^_^

Comment: if it dosn't matter , with your codes , tag <a> can jump to the new page but without the attribute "active", how could I  solve this problem , thanks for pixelscript , your are a good man  ^_^.

Comment: Oh sorry I was using `link.src` instead of `link.href`. Updated the solution!

Comment: @ pixelscript I had change that too, It also doesn't work. Then I  change  the '/recommed' page and add 'active' to '<a class="leftFocusItem active" href="/recommend"><i class="fa fa-user-plus mr5 text-violet fa-fw"></i>您的关注</a>'  ,It works . Thanks for  your help so much.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking a link causes the browser to *leave the current page* and load a new one.

Any DOM modifications you make to the current page will be lost.

You need to add the class *in the new page*. Ideally, you would do this using server-side code but you could use client-side JavaScript by comparing `location.href` to the `href` property of each link in the menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for @Quentin , let me have try.